# Can this valve be removed?

Tags: plumbing, valve, removal, shutoff

[image: shutoff valve]

Where would wrenches go?
Does it need to be cut?

Comment: I have not seen galvanized pipe soldered, are you sure there is not a liquid pipe dope that has dried and you think it's soldered. I would verify this before cutting, a pipe wrench to hold the pipe and a crescent wrench on the flat sides of the valve may be able to unscrew the valve.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like galvanized pipe but I think it's tind copper due to the valve not having a hex shoulder. I'd say take a sharp blade and carefully scratch a layer off the pipe to confirm that it is copper. If so. Cut back after shutting off the water. Clean it with sandpaper until it shines better then new. Then clean it again. Flux and solder. If you are not comfortable soldering, you can use a push on fitting like a Sharkbite.

Answer (score -1):

The valve is soldered onto the pipe. To remove it, you would need to cut the pipe just behind the valve. The new valve would also need a solder connection.

Comment: While it looks like it is soldered it also looks like it could be on galvanized pipe and that would mean it could be threaded. Also if it is soldered on copper it does not mean a new one has to be also soldered, a compression fitting would work.  **TURN OFF THE WATER SUPPLY BEFORE CUTTING**.

Comment: <<You will flood your house unless the water is first shut off>>Yes, it certainly can be removed. It looks solderd on, not threaded. A threaded fitting is usually thicker where the threads engage with the pipe. I would guess you have a 1/2" copper stub out pipe which has been covered with either a patina or some dirt, grime, etc. You can either solder it off or cut it off with a pipe cutter wheel or a mini hacksaw. What do you want to do with once it is off?

Comment: @Alaskaman  is it possibly lead pipe?

Comment: Lol it looks like it might be urine tarnished.

Comment: That which is soldered can be **unsoldered** by application of heat, without cutting the pipe and making it shorter.